# Independence standard normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1 , \dots, X_n$ be independent standard normal variables.

How do I show that $\hat{X}_n$ (average of $X_1 , \dots, X_n$)  is independent with $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i-\hat{X}_n|$ and $(X_1-\hat{X}_n, \dots, X_n -\hat{X}_n)$?

My attempt for the second part:

I check whether $Cov(X_i-\hat{X}_n,\hat{X}_n)=0$ as follows:

$$\mathsf{Cov}(X_i-\hat{X}_n,\hat{X}_n)=\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,\hat{X}_n)-\mathsf{Cov}(\hat{X}_n,\hat{X}_n)=\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,\hat{X}_n)-\mathsf{Var}(\hat{X}_n)=$$$$\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,\hat{X}_n)-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum \mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)-\frac{\sigma^2}{n} $$

Since $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent for $i \neq j$:

$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum \mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=0 $$

Is this correct? And how to show the first part?

Comment: First you need to provide the definition of $\hat{X}_n$

Comment: Thanks for the comment, BGM.  I thought that that would be straightforward, but I edited it: It's the average of $X_1, \dots, X_n$.

Comment: Showing that $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$ is not sufficient for independence.

Comment: @Yannik In general it is not sufficient, but if $X,Y$ have a joint normal distribution then it is sufficient.

Comment: @drhab A yes, I remember now, but $\tfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i - \hat{X}_n|$ is not multivariate normal distributed, so for that you would have to do some more work

Comment: Sorrry but $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i-\hat{X}_n|$ is a function of the vector $(X_1-\hat{X}_n, \dots, X_n -\hat{X}_n)$ and the vector $(X_1-\hat{X}_n, \dots, X_n -\hat{X}_n)$ is independent of $\hat{X}_n$ hence the independence of $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i-\hat{X}_n|$ and $\hat{X}_n$ is the easy part here.

Comment: Correct. The first part is a direct consequence. If $Y$ and $(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ are independent then so are $Y$ and $f(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ where $f$ denotes a suitable function.

Comment: Thanks Did and Drhab! Is there a name for the theorem/proposition that $f(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ is independent from $Y$, if $Y$ is independent from $(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$? I'd like to delve deeper into it! Anyone can give me a reference? I also added a proof of the second part. Is it correct?

Comment: It is elementary. $P(Y\in A\wedge f(Z)\in B)=P(Y\in A\wedge Z\in f^{-1}(B))=P(Y\in A)P(Z\in f^{-1}(B))=P(Y\in A)P(f(Z)\in B)$. This also if $Z$ denotes a vector. Your second proof is correct (as I said in my former comment).